# Change attributes dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am running a loop which is appending input fields. Now, as I am using a loop, all the attributes are similars. So, when I need to grab any one of the then I am grabbing more than one field.

How do I dynamically change the attributes according to the index, so that I can grab the correct input field ?

```
 ebs_no = data.number_ebs;

 for(i=0;i<ebs_no;i++){
   $('form.ebs').append("<br>EBS"+(i+1)+"</br>");
   $('form.ebs').append('<br> SNAPSHOTNO <input type="text" name="'+i+'"></br>');
   $('form.ebs').append('<input type="submit" name="submit">');

   $('[name='+i+']').on('submit',function(){
     alert($('[name='+i+']').val());
   });
  }
```

Comment: provide some `html` too!! You don't need to attach event inside `for loop`

Comment: What do you mean by _"I am grabbing more than one field"_? Show us the code that is doing that.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i am just appending evrything in this form                               <form method='post' action='/ebs' class='ebs' >
 </form>

Comment: what's the value of `data.number_ebs`?

Answer (score 0):

Your are looking for **event delegation**.It is used for created Dynamically DOM elements and use class instead of iterare i in the loop

```
ebs_no = data.number_ebs;
for (i = 0; i < ebs_no; i++) {
    $('form.ebs').append("<br>EBS" + (i + 1) + "</br>");
    $('form.ebs').append('<br> SNAPSHOTNO <input type="text" class="someClass" name="' + i + '"></br>');
    $('form.ebs').append('<input type="submit" name="submit">');
    $('[name=' + i + ']').on('submit', function () {
        alert($('[name=' + i + ']').val());
    });
}
$(document).on('submit', '.someClass', function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
alert($('[name='+i+']').val());
```

by this:

```
alert($(this).val());
```

The code `$(this)` refers to the element being treated